# Oracle Column/Value size Issue

Tags: c#, oracle, copy, odp.net, bulk

I'm using ODP.NET and Oracle 10g to transfer data from a datatable to a db table.
The problem i'm facing is when trying to insert a value into a NUMBER(12,3) column. The value is 100100100,55 - i get the error :
Error in row '1' column '6'
ORA-26093: input data column size (24) exceeds the maximum input size (22)

But if i try 100100100,5 it works ok

This error message has no meaning to me.

Can anyone explain me why ?
Thanks!

Also here's a snippet that throws that error :

```
        OracleBulkCopy bc = new OracleBulkCopy(DBFacade.DbConnection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add();
        dt.Rows.Add(100100100.11);
        bc.DestinationTableName = "tmp_import_bom";
        bc.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "QTY");
        bc.WriteToServer(dt);
```

Comment: Thinking about it I think my answer is not helpful so I deleted it, I think there is something Oracle specific to this error, in that it seems to say that your number with a total of 12 digits is size 24 and can't fit in size 22. I'd suggest editing this question, especially the title, to make it a generic Oracle question and you might get a lot more people looking at it and hopefully a better answer.

Comment: Your column is 12,3 so how come you are getting exceeds maximum input of 22 ?

Comment: what is the version of ODP.net

Comment: it's 11.1.0. I've also edited the question and added a sample of c# code that throws that exception

Comment: I wonder whether `100100100.11` is being stored internally as a floating-point number, which perhaps is not possible to store exactly in just 2 places after the decimal point. Normally, however, I would expect that on sending to Oracle it would automatically truncate any floating-point number to the required precision. Interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a DataTable column like that in your example code, `dt.Columns.Add()`, it **defaults to type string**.

I had a similar issue and discovered the problem is that **oracle bulk copy cannot handle converting strings to decimal or long when the string length exceeds 11**.

To workaround, you need to make sure the source data type is decimal or long, instead of string. In your example code, you could do that with `dt.Columns.Add("QTY", typeof(decimal))`;

Details:

From what I gather, the error message is actually telling us that the max string length for such a conversion is 11. Those (24) and (22) references in the message are the string lengths of the input and maximum allowed x 2. My string coming in was 26641778.595 which is length 12 including the decimal point. If I added a digit, the message changed to (26) etc. Again, I also had the same issue with a plain old number, like 123456789012 which is length 12.

Answer (score 1):

A `NUMBER(12,3)` should hold the values you are trying with no problem.  And if you were exceeding the precision of a number column, more likely the error you are getting would be `ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column`.

It sounds like the error could be related to a different column in the table.  You appear to only be specifying one column on your insert, but the error references `column '6'`.  What are the other columns in the table?

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered in Oracle doument "OracleBulkCopy Throws ORA-26093 When Inserting into NUMBER Column With Precision (Doc ID 1382276.1)".

In short:

> CAUSE: This is by design and expected behavior. The default type is
>   System.String.
>
> SOLUTION: Specify column datatype

So instead of:

> ```
> dt.Columns.Add();
> ```

one should write:

> ```
> DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
> dc.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Double");
> dc.ColumnName = "QTY";
> dt.Columns.Add(dc);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually due to a metadata missmatch- not a value error. Confirm that the data type you are using on the .Net side is consistent with the number(12,3) column specification on the ORacle side. Try passing it as 'double' (converting to double in the application) and see if that resolves the issue.